# Subir proyecto laravel a un VPS, usando Nginx, sin usar Git

Tags: php, html, laravel, webservice, git

tengo una duda, ya busqué en Google y no encuentro una respuesta convincente, tengo un VPS, ya está configurado el servidor Nginx, ya pude iniciar una página con Laravel y pude acceder a él desde internet utilizando un dominio, el problema está en que mis desarrollos sobre Laravel los voy a hacer en mi PC, he estado investigando y al parecer en necesario usar un repositorio Git para poder subir mis cambios en mis proyectos y una vez estando ahí obtenerlos en mi servidor, pero quisiera saber si es factible subir de manera manual las carpetas cada vez que vaya a realizar una actualización, es decir borrar toda la carpeta de Laravel de mi servidor y subir la actualizada desde mi PC, me gustaría saber si habría problemas al hacer eso.

Answer (score 0):

Pues no necesariamente, solo create una conexión ftp o una ssh, la que sea mas de tu preferencia, en lo particular yo uso una ssh para usar la consola de comandos y poder ejecutar directamente en la vps comandos de artisan.

Ahora la forma de trabajar:

-Yo uso visual studio code con la extension ftp-simple, tienes que configurar la conexion para que esta este guardando los cambios directamente en el servidor.

Te dejo el link de la extension.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=humy2833.ftp-simple

Para abrir las configuraciones solo tienes que oprimir ctrl+shif+p y en la ventanita que te aparece pon ftp-simple y selecciona la opcion que dice config
en la pagina que te abre tienes que poner los datos de tu coneccion ftp

```
[
    {
        "name": "Nombre de tu coneccion",
        "host": "tu dominio o el ip de tu dominio", (si no sabes como obtenerlo le el apendice)
        "port": 'puerto,
        "type": "tipo de conexion",
        "username": "usuario",
        "password": "contraseña ",
        "path": "El directorio donde esta almacenado tu proyecto",
        "autosave": true, // si quiere que auto guarde sin preguntar
        "confirm": false // si quieres que no aparezca la el cuadro de dialogo diciendo que se va a modificar el archivo
    },

]
```

Ahora para iniciar la coneccion solo aprime ctrl+shif+p y en la ventanita escribe ftp-simple y escoge la opción que dice remote-directory open to workspace

Y listo.

apendice

Si por algun motivo no puedes conectarte directamente con el ip puedes hacer un ping a tu dominio en esta pagina.

https://www.ipaddressguide.com/ping

o directamente en tu consola solo pones

```
ping tu-dominio.com
```

y precionas enter, eso te dará el ip de tu dominio

Si no quieres utilizar visual stuido code púede utilizar cualquier otro editor, solo busca en google como conectarte desde el via ftp o ssh.

Yo uso como ya comente visual studio code, y sobre puty utilizo mi conexion ssh para correr comandos artisan o comando de nodejs (webpack)